# Find limit of this expression

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(x)}{\cot(x)}\ $$

Already tried using L'Hopitals rule like this :

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)}{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}\ $$ so I'd get ($\frac{0}{0}$) but didn't help.

Comment: What is $ctg(x)$?

Comment: ctg(x) or cot(x); cotangent

Comment: $$\left|\frac{\log(x)}{\cot(x)}\right|=\left|\frac{\sin(x)\log(x)}{\cos(x)}\right|\le \left|\frac{x\log(x)}{\cos(x)}\right|$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use L'Hospital:$$\lim_{ x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(x)}{\cot(x)}=-\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}\times\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x)$$

$$=0$$

Comment: How did you get to that expression ? o:O

Comment: Which expression?

Comment: You're missing a limit after the first "equals" sign

Comment: @Dr.MV Oh yes right! Thanks!

Comment: Are we allowed to use L'Hospital if numerator tends to -infinity and denominator tends to +infinity ?

Comment: @JamesGroon yes.

Comment: WOW I DID NOT KNOW THAT . just spent 1 hour on this -_- .Thanks.

Comment: @JamesGroon The reason you can is the following. Suppose $f(x)\to -\infty$ and $g(x)\to +\infty$. Then $-f(x)\to +\infty$, so 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=-\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{-f(x)}{g(x)}=-\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{-f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$
We use L'Hopital's rule in the middle step, as $-f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both approaching $+\infty$.

Comment: @kccu Thank you! I think he'd have figured it out himself! In any case.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the limit makes sense only when $x \to 0^{+}$ and then it is an easy consequence of the following standard limits $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x} = 1,\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}x\log x = 0$$ We have $$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\log x}{\cot x} = \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\tan x}{x}\cdot x\log x = 1\cdot 0 = 0$$